# Addon object using PropertyGroup object attribute

Tags: scripting, add-on

I'm working on adaptation some addon from 2.79 to 2.8x.
It uses property groups to fill other objects with recurring attributes.

```
TestProps:
my_float_prop: bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=3.1415926)

MyCustomNode:
my_float_prop: TestProps.my_float_prop
```

With 2.79 using `=` assignment addon works fine.
But 2.8x with pep-0526 I'm getting

```
AttributeError: type object 'TestProps' has no attribute 'my_float_prop'
```

I had created [github repo](https://github.com/Begalov/test_props) demonstrates my problem with same project structure.

Comment: Hi. Any *relevant* code (like a basic working example that still demonstrates the issue) should be in the question body itself. Thanks.

Comment: It is now defined as an annotation.  Try something like `TestProp.__annotations__["my_float_prop"]`   Consider too using `math.pi`.

Comment: Thanks, batFINGER. That wotks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using annotations rather than class properties**

It is now defined as an annotation. They are added to a key value dictionary `__annotations__` on the class on which they are defined. Try something like

```
TestProp.__annotations__["my_float_prop"]
```

There is a generic `Namespace` class where can

```
from argparse import Namespace
props = Namespace(**TestProp.__annotations__)
```

and then access them via

```
props.test_float_prop
```

Consider too using `math.pi`.

Comment: Another thanks for Namespace solution